# SimpleDateFormat for 2018-05-19T04:51:29.6702751+00:00

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

The date from server is coming as `2018-05-19T04:51:29.6702751+00:00`. 
I need to convert this string in `Date object` in **Android**.

I don't know how to handle the part after "+" sign

Comment: do you want to remove the data after + sign or what, thwn convert into DAte Object

Comment: trim the text off after + sign and convert into Date object

Comment: I want to use that data. It gives the GMT time zone which will affect the resulting Date in current time zone (where the user is)

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Java-8 you can parse the string using [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class something like:

```
    ZonedDateTime d = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-05-19T04:51:29.6702751+00:00");
    Date date = Date.from(d.toInstant());
    System.out.println(date.toString());
```

For Java-7 you can do like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatwithzone = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSXXX");
    Date date1 = formatwithzone.parse("2018-05-19T04:51:29.6702751+05:30");
    System.out.println(date1.toString());
```

Comment: The correct answer. May use `OffsetDateTime`. Unless a `Date` object is needed for some legacy API, one would prefer to stay with the `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`. Similar code works on pre-level-26 Android too when you use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). In this case the conversion goes like `Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(d.toInstant()):`.

Comment: My minimum API level is 21 and none of these are working there

Comment: I am assuming API level 21 is compatible with JDK 7.

Comment: @Kishita The `ZonedDateTime` version works. The long explanation of what you need to do for it to work is [in this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). The Android edition of `SimpleDateFormat` may sometimes behave differently from the standard Java 7 one. In any case that class is troublesome.

Comment: When I run the Java-7 snippet from the answer on Oracle Java in my time zone; I expect the time 01:21:29 because I am at UTC offset +02:00, so difference should be three and a half hours. However I get `Sat May 19 03:13:11 CEST 2018`. It’s still possible Android Java behaves better. I’ve heard that it handles more than three `S` in the format pattern string as expected, which a standard `SimpleDateFormat` doesn’t, as we just saw.